# .htaccess subfolder redirect to root files

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website inside another websites folder. Its accessed http://websiteone.com/websitetwo

There is a domain websitetwo.com which simply redirects users to the above domain/subfolder.

I am wondering if there is a way using .htaccess to redirect http://websiteone.com/websitetwo to read files in the web root directory websitetwo.com without actually redirecting the user so to make it appear they are still on http://websiteone.com/websitetwo

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just drop the redirect?

Comment: Maybe but the domain is owned by a client and we manage the application. That will be a conversation if this cant be done.